# How can you preserve array bound values and use them in a function declaration?

Tags: c++

Suppose I use main() to read from a file and occupy a 2D array `int arr[S1][S2]` where `S1` and `S2` are determined from the file.  If I wanted to pass this array into a function, how can I write the multidimensional array as a function parameter with the correct bounds `S1` and `S2`?

```
int some_function(int arr_copy[S1][S2], ...);

int main()
{
/* read file and occupy arr[S1][S2] */
}
```

Obviously the above is a problem because `S1` and `S2` are undefined.

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` ? The size is queryable from the object plus available iterators.

Comment: Just to be clear, are `S1` and `S2` always the same, or are you planning to call `some_function()` with differently-shaped arrays?

Comment: They can change depending on the input file.

Comment: Why are you using C and tagging code as C++?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm coding in C++.

Comment: @hmjd aside from this problem, the array makes my total task easier to intuitively work with.

Comment: @BobJohn you *think* you are coding in C++, but the first parameter is C-style array.

Comment: @BobJohn, a `vector` has `operator[]` and the underlying raw array can be accessed via `&v[0]` (or `v.data()`).

Comment: @hmjd If he really has a matrix, then `vector<vector>` is usually not a good idea, since it allows ragged edges.  The only good way to handle this is to define a Matrix class, which uses a `vector<int>` to hold the data, and does the index calculations itself.

Comment: @BobJohn If they can change according to the input file, how do you declare the array in `main`.  In a definition like `int array[S1][S2];`, `S1` and `S2` must be compile time constants.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious solution would be to write a Matrix class based on
`std::vector`, and use that.  You would then declare the
function to take a (probably `const`) reference to the matrix,
and be done with it.  It's a lot easier than any of the
alternatives, and a lot safer.

If you really insist on using the C style array in `main`, then
you can define the function as a template:

```
template <size_t S1, size_t S2>
int
some_function( int const (&array)[S1][S2], ...) ...
```

The compiler will determine the actual values of `S1` and `S2`
from the declaration of the array you pass.

Comment: Is the template option particularly expensive?  The function is relatively small, but will it affect runtime significantly over, say, "a Matrix class based on std::vector" if it's called a large number of times?

Comment: If anything, the template option will result in better performance.  If the function is instantiated a lot, for different dimensions, it may result in code bloat.  The most important restriction, obviously, is that `S1` and `S2` must be compile time constants (but this restriction also applies to `int array[S1][S2]`).

Answer (score 1):

If you must pass an array, then the function should take an `int*` and two arguments for the bounds.  It would be better to use a container class for the array, passed by reference (or const reference).

EDIT: For all that, do what James recommends with the templates.  :-)

Comment: If he has a `int array[S1][S2]`, then he can't easily convert it into an `int*`.  The type would be `int (*pArray)[S2]`.